# setState is not updating DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have  this component in my react app. This basically update the state after every second. But The value `<p>{this.state.time}</p>` is not changing. I print the value of state it is changing after every second.

```
import React from 'react'

import './style.css'

class List extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            time:420
        }
        this.handleCountdown = this.handleCountdown.bind(this)
    }

    handleCountdown(){
        console.log('4')
        console.log(this.state)
        setInterval(()=>{
            this.setState({time:this.state.time-1})
            console.log('here')
            console.log(this.state)
        },1000)
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        console.log('1')
        if(this.props.start != nextProps.start){
            console.log('in')
            if(nextProps.start == false){
                this.setState({time:420})
                console.log('2')
                return true
            }
            else if(nextProps.start == true){
                this.handleCountdown()
                console.log('3')
                return true
            }
        }else{
            return false
        }
    }

    render(){
        {console.log(this.state)}                                               
        return(
            <div className="test-clock">
                <p>{this.state.time}</p>
                <p className='test-clock-subheading'>{this.props.start=='true'?'Min remaining':'Start sudo contest'}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default List
```

It is child component. I import it to parent and then use it.
Can any body tell why DOM is not updating?

> this.forceUpdate() will update the DOM. But why this.setState() is not
>   updating DOM?

Comment: This is the reason why you should use the getDerivedStateFromProps lifecycle method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to check if your state has changed. Add the following to your `shouldComponentUpdate` method.

```
}
else if ( this.state.time !== nextState.time {
  return true;
}
```

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate):

> Use `shouldComponentUpdate()` to let React know if a component’s output
>   is not affected by the current change in **state or props**.